# Getting 502 Proxy Error on JMeter during the load run

Tags: proxy, jmeter, webserver, apache2

I am getting a 502 Proxy Error as mentioned below for some of the requests on the load run using JMeter Non-GUI Mode. On the local this is happening for a few of the requests. We are using a separate proxy server and also two Apache2 web servers.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>502 Proxy Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Proxy Error</h1>
<p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.<br />
The proxy server could not handle the request<p>Reason: <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong></p></p>
</body></html>
```

The below error is seen on the apache2 error logs also.

```
[Wed Jul 20 08:39:31.380511 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 52712:tid 140054629893888] [client 202.83.19.25:39328] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /cnp/remotepay/r, referer: https://perf.ezetap.com/cnp/remotepay/pay?token=2zO77fS5LBz0xW07ctH0
```

What might be the reason for this? The configuration remains the same on both the apache2 servers.

Answer (score 0):

> Error reading from remote server

[means that your proxy couldn't get response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/502) from the underlying Apache2 web server.

We cannot state what is the reason behind this without seeing logs and other metrics my assumptions are:

- Check [apache error log](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#errorlog), it might be the case it contains the reason for the failure
- Apache2 servers are not properly configured for high loads, make sure to follow [Apache Performance Tuning](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/misc/perf-tuning.html) tips
- It might also be the case the operating system where Apache runs lacks resources like CPU, RAM, Network, Disk or whatever, you can re-run your test with monitoring of these (and other applicable) parameters, if you don't have a better solution you can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-metrics) for this
- If your web application uses database you might also want to check database configuration in terms of maximum connections, inspect [slow query logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html), [deadlocks](https://www.sqlshack.com/what-are-sql-server-deadlocks-and-how-to-monitor-them/) and so on